# Debugging Javascript error which only affects IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, access-denied

On a site I look after, http://bit.ly/1lEAHes, a javascript error is breaking the slider, but only in IE9. Line 104 appears to be the problem, creating an "Access is denied" error message:

```
for (k = 0; k < s.rules.length; k++) {
```

in the following section:

```
for (j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
        s = r[j];
        var n = [];
        for (k = 0; k < s.rules.length; k++) {
            var css = s.rules[k].cssText || s.rules[k].style.cssText;
            if (!css) {
                continue;
            }
```

but I'm a javascript novice and don't know how to fix it...whether it is a typo in the code, a conflict with some other code on the page or something else. Can anyone help and prevent yet another long, frustrating and fruitless night of trial-and-error?!

Answer (score 0):

Tried debugging at the url you specified, looks like something to do with the stylesheets/css rules not being accessible for the following url
"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Droid+Sans&subset=latin,&v2"
Do you include this url somewhere in your html pages? or some external plugin?

Check what's wrong there..

Comment: I've tracked that down and fixed it, thanks @horse shoe, but it hasn't made any difference. Any other ideas?